# Custom sorting method Excel VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I have a column of numbers, that have to be sorted like this:

I have one number in A1, which is the precise value from I start -e.g. 
`10` and then I have numbers like:
`9, 8.1, 11, 6, 10.5`

My goal is to sort them from the least different. It means:

```
10, 10.5, 11, 9, 8.1, 6.
```

In Java it would be done by compareTo function. Is there something like this is VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no cleaner way exists you could try the following workaround :

define a distance function like this : **abs(x - from)** and sort by its results, maybe in a temporary/hidden sheet if you want to apply sort in a transparent manner.

Comment: +1 that seems clean enough to me :). I'd just put it in a column, hidden or otherwise, in the same sheet. (You might want to edit the first word of your answer for future generations.)